# generic `any` function for Java

Tags: java, generics

I have various `Node`, `Token` and other classes.  Each class has its own `Type` enum.

I have lists of nodes, and lists of tokens, and lists of other things.

And I often want to see if there are any items of a particular `Type` in a list.

For example, to see if there are any *keywords* in a list of tokens, I'd loop over them:

```
Token found = null;
for(Token token: statement)
    if(token.type == Token.Type.KEYWORD &&
      (token.token.equals("static") ||
      (token.token.equals("final")) {
        found = token;
        break;
    }
if(found != null) {
    ....
```

If I write little helpers, I can tidy up my code a lot (as I want to work out what's in lists a lot):

```
Token any(Collection<Token> haystack,Token.Type type,String... needles) {
   for(Token straw: haystack)
       if(straw.type == type)
            for(String needle: needles)
                if(needle.equals(straw.token))
                    return straw;
   return null;
}
```

Then, elsewhere, I can:

```
if((found = any(statement,Token.Type.KEYWORD,"static","final")) != null)
   ...
```

Is there any way to generalise this for `Node` and other variables, and for comparisons that are not strings and where the fields are different, and named differently?

With C++ templates you can duck type; with Java, I'm struggling to see how to do this although making classes comparable to their own types and so on might be a way forward?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Things that you would use duck typing for can usually be accomplished with interfaces in java. Consider this interface:

```
public interface Typed<T extends Enum<T>> {
    T getType();
    String getToken();
}
```

Then you can change your `any` method to use only types that implement this interface:

```
public <A extends Enum<A>, B extends Typed<A>> B any(Collection<B> haystack, A type, String... needles) {
    for (B straw : haystack)
        if (straw.getType().equals(type))
            for (String needle : needles)
                if (needle.equals(straw.getToken()))
                    return straw;
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use duck typing with reflections in Java but it is likely to be

- more complicated, rather than simpler
- much more error prone

I suggest you stick to what is simplest to write and understand.

```
FOUND: {
  for(Token token: statement)
    if(token.type == Token.Type.KEYWORD &&
      (token.token.equals("static") ||
      (token.token.equals("final")) {
        // handle token here
        break FOUND;
    }
  // handle not found here
}
```

instead of using a label you can create a method and return when you found a match.

I suspect the KEYWORD check is redundant here as I assume you can't have `static` or `final` and it not be a keyword.  A more efficient way of doing this is something like.

```
static final List<String> KEYWORDS_TO_MATCH = Arrays.asList("static", "final");

FOUND: {
   for(Token token: statement)
     if(KEYWORDS_TO_MATCH.contains(token.token)) {
        // handle token here
        break FOUND;
     }
   // handle not found here
}
```